# Why does gravity cause things to fall, as opposed to just remaining stationary?

Tags: general-relativity

I currently hold a pen in my hand. While it rests in my hand, nothing happens. Yet the moment I release my grip, it will move relative to me. Specifically, it will fall to the floor at a rate of 10 m/s^2 even if nothing visibly pushes or pulls on it, the same way I might push a box to move it.

Why?

Comment: Being invisible doesn't mean it doesn't exists. The action your finger exerts on the pen is also invisible at a small scale, but is a force that acts at distance such as the gravity.

Comment: To understand this completely, you would need to do an indepth study of Einstein's General Relativity.  But for a start, take a look at this short video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzjA5d0QXv8

Comment: Masses like the Earth warp time and space towards its center (which is gravity). Gravity causes your pen to fall since the pen is being carried by curved spacetime.  Unlike electromagnetic or nuclear forces, spacetime is ingrained into the background of the universe, making it so that its only manifestations occur when a mass is present.  Even something as massless as light isn't immune to having to follow paths altered by spacetime curvature.

Comment: You should familiarise yourself with the concept of a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_field). Here, it is a gravitational field, or any region where an object with mass (Newtonian physics) experiences a force. There are other examples of fields, like the electric field, where objects with electric charge experience a force.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that the answer is because the pen is always moving through space-time, and that freefall is simply the shortest "path" through spacetime?

Answer (score 2):

Objects can exert force on each other at a distance, but let's try to dig deeper. In the framework of Newtonian mechanics, when an object accelerates we say that there is a force (or more forces) that causes that acceleration, and we write this concept as Newton's law
$$\sum_i \vec{F}_i = m\cdot\vec a$$
Now, the most obvious forces are **contact forces**, interactions of two objects touching, but to explain, using this framework (which works really well, that's why we use it) many phenomena, we need to accept the concept of **distance forces**, i.e. forces that objects exert on each other even if they are distant.

This way we can explain, with a simple formula (Newton's law of gravity) why we see planets and other objects accelerate, and even describe with high precision their motion. Gravity is just one of these forces, but you need distance forces to describe also other phenomena, for example, why magnets accelerate when near one another, or why charged materials do (you can do simple demonstrations at home exploiting the triboelectric effect).

So, there is something exerting a force on your pen, it's the Earth pulling it, that's why it's accelerating in a very specific direction (the center of mass of Earth), and this force is at a distance. Actually, your pen is also exerting an opposite force on the Earth itself, you just don't see it moving because you have to consider it's great mass, and the summation of all of the forces acting on it.

So, you may ask, where is this force *before* I release my pen. It's still there, but remember Newton's law as written above, the acceleration you observe is the result of *all* the forces acting on it. When you hold it you are exerting a force (a contact one in this case) on it, exactly equal in modulus, but in the opposite direction to gravity, so that the sum (as vectors) of all the forces is zero and the acceleration you observe it's zero.

Comment: This answer is based on Newtonian concepts of gravity.  These have been completely supplanted by General Relativity.  It does not require two objects to have gravity.  One single planet warps spacetime so that even massless light is attracted.

Comment: Yes, I based the answer on the framework of newtonian mechanics, it would be interesting if other people answered in the framework of General relativity (which I am not prepared enough to do) and also in the framework maybe of QFT, because I think the doubt here is not only about gravity, but the concept of interaction at a distance in general.

Answer (score 0):

When the pen is in your hand, gravity is still "pulling" on it even though it does not move. The palm of you hand pushes up countering the weight, preventing it from falling down.

If you change the pen to a 2 Kg weight, you will certainly feel that gravity is pulling the weight down, and you have to work hard to keep that weight from falling(accelerating).

If you were suddenly to disappear, then pen, like the 2Kg weight, will start to fall down.

Another example of invisible force is magnets.